# How do I set a custom resolution in Civilization VI?

Tags: civilization-6

In Civilization V, there is a file in the user documents that you can change to set a custom resolution, but the file no longer exists in Civilization VI. Is there a way I can set a custom resolution in Civilization VI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file in which you can change your resolution still exists, just under a different name.

`Documents > My Games > Sid Meier's Civilization VI > AppOptions.txt`

After opening that file in a text editor, scroll to the `[Video]` section, and find the `RenderWidth` and `RenderHeight` variables. That part of the file will look like this:

```
;Render width in pixels.
RenderWidth 1920

;Render height in pixels.
RenderHeight 1080
```

The numbers that come after `RenderWidth` and `RenderHeight` are what you want to change to your custom resolution. The example shown above is for a 1920x1080 resolution.

Comment: When installed on linux through steam running the windows version with ProtonGE, I found the AppOptions-file here:

`~/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/compatdata/289070/pfx/drive_c/users/steamuser/AppData/Local/Firaxis Games/Sid Meier's Civilization VI/AppOptions.txt`

Note the `289070/` folder in the `steamapps/compatdata/` directory, as far as I saw there seems to be one such virtual virtual windows disk per game besides the install files. I saw no pattern to the naming, so might be that it could change with updates, but I doubt it as it would break the players saved preferences over time.